# Clone & Appendto - Can't Get It to Work (JS Newb)

Tags: javascript, clone, appendto

Wow. Both of those worked perfectly. Thank you!!!

One more follow-up question. Say I had 4 different Tabcontent Divs with unique classes. And I want to append the Getit class to all tabcontent Divs...

If I just appendTo 'tabcontent' it adds it to the bottom of all 'tabcontent' divs, which is great. BUT, then I have the same content duplicated with the GetIt ID. How can I make it so that if someone has selected the GetIt in my tabbed nav, that the clone won't appear but it will appear in all other tabcontent classes?

Here was my original problem:

First, let me say that I don't know much Javascript. Just trying to piece something together here.

My problem is this:

I want to take one Div ID, clone it and append it to another Div ID without changing any content.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="tabcontent" id="Getit"> Buy my widgets</div>
<div class="tabcontent" id="History"> History of my widgets</div>
```

I want to Copy/Clone the 'Getit' ID and append it to the end of the 'History' ID.

Currently, my Javascript code looks like this:

```
$('#tabcontent .Getit').clone().appendTo('#tabcontent .History');
```

I appreciate any help that you can offer.

Thank you!

Comment: `.` is a class selector, `#` is an ID selector. `.Getit` will give you back an array of class selected elements, not an `id` selected element. Try `#Getit`. Also, the same goes for `#History`. Also, you want to do `#Getit.tabcontent` and `#History.tabcontent` (note, no space, which is a descendent selector) to select an element with both.

Comment: Note that you should explictly set the ID of the cloned element to something different. (Don't have more than one element with the same ID.)

Comment: Thank you! That worked so well! Any chance you could take a look at the updated question now that I'm understanding this a little better?

Comment: @Perry - I'd prefer you to upvote the answers and mark one as the answer, and open a new question with the new request.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector `'#tabcontent .Getit'` searches for all `.Getit` elements which are children from `#tabcontent`. I don't think that is what you want.

This should do it:

```
$('#Getit').clone( true ).appendTo('#History');
```

Calling `.clone()` with parameter `true` causes it to clone all attached data & events aswell. However, that is optional.

Comment: `document.getElementByID("History").appendChild(document.getElementById("GetIt").cloneNode(true));`

Comment: don't say the forbidden word in my comments !

Comment: Right, when it's an ID selector, you don't need ancestors. Always forget that when I'm looking at other code.

Answer (score 0):

`.` is a class selector, `#` is an ID selector. `#tabcontent` is looking for a unique ID'd element, `.Getit` will give you back an array of class selected elements, not an id selected element.

Try `.tabcontent#Getit`. Also, the same goes for `#History`. You want to do `#Getit.tabcontent` and `#History.tabcontent` or reversed (note, no space, which is a descendent selector) to select an element with both.

```
<div class="tabcontent" id="Getit"> Buy my widgets</div>
<div class="tabcontent" id="History"> History of my widgets</div>

$('.tabcontent#Getit').clone().appendTo('.tabcontent#History');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qreQ5/

Note, you will also want to deal with the `id` attribute of the clone somehow. For example:

```
$('.tabcontent#Getit').clone().attr('id','test').appendTo('.tabcontent#History');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qreQ5/2/

Comment: Thank you! That worked so well! Any chance you could take a look at the updated question now that I'm understanding this a little better?